# python 3.5 on windows. the program should send a text file which it reads and it sends an emty message

Tags: python, gmail

tried it before and it worked don't know what happend..
 at first it should read a text file. and I've tried reading and printing it manually and it worked so that part is ok. I think. but every time I try to send the message I get an empty message

```
import smtplib as s

#file settings
filename = open("D:\pythonscripts\hey_hey.txt", 'a+')
content = filename.read()

#recivers list
recivers = ['somemail@gmail.com']

#tries to send the message
def send_mail(username, password, msg):

    #connects to smtp gmail server
    server = s.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com:587')
    server.starttls()
    server.login(username, password)
    try:
        server.sendmail(username, recivers[0], msg)
        print("massage sent")
    except:
        server.close()
        print("error while sending the massage\nquitung server...")


send_mail('somemail@gmail.com', 'ferari_car', content)
```

Comment: hey i executed a print statment before sending the mail and it printed the message just fine, so like you said i guess it's something with the mail.. but i still don't get it..

Answer (score 2):

Try this instead:

```
filename = open("D:\\pythonscripts\\hey_hey.txt", 'r')  # r, not a+, and escape the backslashes
```

`a+` opens the file for appending, which puts the file position at the end of the file. So when you try to read it, you'll get nothing.

Comment: See my edit. You also forgot to escape the backslashes in the path.

Comment: That said, I'm not 100% sure the escaping matters in this specific case, if that's your actual path. Since `\p` and `\h` aren't actual things, I think Python should handle this okay. (You should still definitely fix it, but let me know if you're still having trouble after that.)

Comment: Try a `print(content)` after the `content = ...` line to see if you're successfully reading the file. (If not, you don't need to bother testing sending the actual email, since the problem is before that. If you *are* successfully reading the file, then you can proceed to debugging the email sending.)

Answer (score 0):

hey all thank you for helping me out. evenchely I managed to send the message with the text file as an attachment instead of the message's body..

```
import smtplib as s
from os.path import basename
from email.mime.application import MIMEApplication
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.utils import COMMASPACE, formatdate

#file settings
filename = open("D:\\pythonscripts\\hey_hey.txt", 'r')
content= filename.read()
print(content)

#recivers list
recivers = ['somemail@gmail.com']

#tries to send the message
def send_mail(username, password, message, send_to, subject):
    #message settings
    msg = MIMEMultipart()
    msg['From'] = username
    msg['To'] = COMMASPACE.join(send_to)
    msg['Date'] = formatdate(localtime=True)
    msg['Subject'] = subject
    msg.attach(MIMEText(message))

    #connects to smtp gmail server
    server = s.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com:587')
    server.starttls()
    server.login(username, password)
    try:
        server.sendmail(username, send_to, msg.as_string())
        print("massage sent")
    except:
        server.close()
        print("error while sending the massage\nquitung server...")


send_mail('othermail@gmail.com', 'ferari_car', content, recivers[0], "the mail stuff")
```